# Android - Moving text issue

Tags: android

I'm trying to create moving text.I have crated surface view and thread for looping it.but it not show me a moving motion but draw that text each after like  *****  ** *** *** in infinite.

But what I need was move that this point to that** -> ** got it?

this is my code

```
package com.CurvePackage.Curve;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Origin extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    Context context1;
    private MainThread thread;
    private int x=0;
    private int y=0;


    public Origin(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        context1 = context;
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

        setFocusable(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextSize(23);
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        // int score=(10-sprites.size()*100);
        x=x+20;
        y=y+20;
        canvas.drawText("ewqewqe", x, y, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        // Toast.makeText(getba, "Replay clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        thread.setRunning(false);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      boolean retry = true;
//      while (retry) {
//          try {
//              thread.join();
//              retry = false;
//          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//              // try again shutting down the thread
//          }
//      }

    }
}
```

Main Thread

```
package com.CurvePackage.Curve;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MainThread extends Thread {

    // flag to hold game state
    private boolean running;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Origin origin;
     static final long FPS = 15;

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;

        while (running) {
            Canvas c = null;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                   c = origin.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                   synchronized (origin.getHolder()) {
                       origin.onDraw(c);
                   }
            } finally {
                   if (c != null) {
                       origin.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                   }
            }


            sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            try {
                   if (sleepTime > 0)
                          sleep(sleepTime);
                   else
                          sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

    }

    public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Origin origin) {
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.origin = origin;
    }

}
```

Comment: What you want to do you want to move your text as Headlines or something else

Comment: I need to see the text moving thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to paint the entire background in your onDraw method, before you paint your text.

```
Paint p2 = new Paint();
p2.setStyle(Style.FILL);
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, p2);
//draw text here
```

This will completely paint over the text from the previous time the canvas was drawn, and will remove this dragging effect.

Comment: Is this the perfect solution for this?

Comment: I tried it but its not working..text not moving but show still at the begging ???

Comment: This is not about dragging but..it should move automatically!!

Comment: I don't know about perfect. Android does not clean the canvas every time it draws, it keeps painting over itself. So to avoid any dragging/blurring problems you need to draw over the canvas, or at least the area that was previously drawn on, with something. This can be an image, solid color, texture, whatever.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your problem properly. Can you explain in more detail what the problem is and maybe link some images?

Comment: I need to show that text to be move/motion some way..whatever direction no problem..

Comment: I tried running your code, and works as expected when i remove  the line `setWillNotDraw(false);`

Comment: Yes!! mate that's true its working fine without that..What does it actually mean?? setWillNotDraw(false);

Comment: It is supposed to ensure the onDraw() method is called in an extended surfaceView. Apparently you should remove it if you override the onDraw() method. I don't really know anything about this myself: I was just reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687015/extended-surfaceviews-ondraw-method-never-called

Comment: How to execuete ondraw when touches the screen??

Comment: I need that drawing to be start whe touches the screen

Comment: Use a boolean to control this. Change it to true when the screen is touched, and don't update your x and y values if the boolean is false.

Comment: But I need that to be drawn very time it touches ??

Comment: You can set x and y to 0 when the user touches the screen.