# How to know if SurfaceView really draws/updates its content?

Tags: android, surfaceview, ondraw

I know that `onDraw()` is not being called by `SurfaceView`. Instead, the drawing is done by a separate thread. Is there any way to know each time it is being redrew/updated?

Answer (score 2):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2687093/1629707) answer, you could simple add `setWillNotDraw(false)` to receive the `onDraw()` callback

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could create a custom class that extends whatever view you are using. You could then overwite onDraw() and get it to callback to your main activity (pass it to your extended view)

```
class mButton extends Button {
   private Activity ownerActivity;

   public void setOwner(Activity pA) {
      ownerActivity = pA;
   }

   @override
   public void onDraw() {
      super.onDraw();
      ((MainActivity) ownerActivity).callback();
   }
}
```

Or something along those lines...