# How to draw lines on OpenCV Camera Preview?

Tags: android, opencv, camera, overlay, preview

Im using OpenCV camera preview.

I want to draw a rectangle over the live preview.
Ive tried to override the ondraw method, but I cant see a line.
Please help.

```
package com.example.easymeasure;

import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class CustomOpenCVJavaCameraView extends JavaCameraView {

    public CustomOpenCVJavaCameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private Paint linePaint;
    protected void init() { 
        Resources r = this.getResources();
        linePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        linePaint.setAlpha(200);
        linePaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        linePaint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.marker_color));
        linePaint.setShadowLayer(2, 1, 1, r.getColor(R.color.shadow_color));        
    }

    @Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);       
        linePaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        canvas.drawLine(10,20,1000,200,linePaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could instead draw directly on the mat you're getting with each camera frame.  You could put a border around the outer edges of the mat with Imageproc.rectangle(), line(), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres the solution: [Extended SurfaceView's onDraw() method never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687015/extended-surfaceviews-ondraw-method-never-called)

You simply have to add :

```
setWillNotDraw(false)
```

To the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Another point i would like to add:
After overriding the onDraw method change the view in layout to:

```
<CustomOpenCVJavaCameraView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         />
```